# How to add selfsigned certificate to bundle in git-bash?

Tags: windows, git, curl, trusted-root-certificates

Attempting to update git on a windows machine in git-bash with `git update-git-for-windows` fails with a message from `curl`:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I expected this problem, since we use self-signed certificates. I know it's no good, but I can't change it.

So where would I find the certificate bundle used by curl or git and add my own trusted root-certificate to it?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to find out about your config. You will see your configuration values and where those are stored.

```sh
$ git config --list --show-origin --show-scope
system file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig <key>=<value>
system file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig <key>=<value>
...
global file:C:/Users/<USERNAME>/.gitconfig <key>=<value>
global file:C:/Users/<USERNAME>/.gitconfig <key>=<value>
...
```

Look for the keys `http.sslbackend` and `http.sslcainfo`
Only if `http.sslbackend=openssl` then `http.sslcainfo` will be in play.

This is how its going to look on the commandline

```
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslbackend=openssl
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Now you also see the file where you can add your CA, open `ca-bundle.crt` and append your company-certificate to it.

Now there won't be a problem with the self signed certificate in certificate chain anymore.